# Use WHERE IN operator with DESC LIMIT 1 for Each ID

Tags: sql, node.js, cassandra, greatest-n-per-group, cql

I have a table in Cassandra, which stores the tenant's last updated details.
There is a timestamp field that updates usage. I need to find the last updated detail for every tenant.
So, consider the table structure to be like this :

[image]

Now, I need output like this:

[image]

I have written query like this :

```
aQueries = ['t1','t2','t3'];
const query = `SELECT * 
  FROM system_log_stats.keyspaces_sizes
  WHERE keyspace_name IN ? ORDER BY  timestamp_sec DESC LIMIT 1`;
const res = await client.execute(query, [aQueries], { prepare: true});
```

But the above query returns just 1 result.

Please note that I have to use where IN clause as I do not want to fetch for all tenants but only selected ones.

Comment: https://howtoprogram.xyz/2017/02/18/using-group-apache-cassandara/

Comment: I think you need to sub-select all the tenant IDs and max values (let's call it `max_table`) and then join to your primary table where `max_table.tenantId = main_table.tenantId and max_table.timestamp = main_table.timestamp`. Simply using the `max()` and `group by` won't work since you're also interested in `usage` value, hence the more complicated join. There's probably a more efficient way, but that would work.

Answer (score 2):

In Cassandra, `LIMIT 1` will only return result of 1 row from entire result set.

Cassandra also provides `PER PARTITION LIMIT 1`, which returns 1 row from *every partition* in the result set.

https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#limiting-results

In your example, you may be able to do something like

```
SELECT * 
  FROM system_log_stats.keyspaces_sizes
  WHERE keyspace_name IN ? ORDER BY  timestamp_sec DESC PER PARTITION LIMIT 1
```

(though I'm not sure ORDER BY can be used at the same time.)

Answer (score 0):

Clean solution would be to use query multiple times in a loop. You can query following in  a loop for list of tenanat Id

```
select * from 
table where tenantd Id =?
ORDER BY  timestamp_sec DESC LIMIT 1
```

Advantages of this solution :

1. Using 'IN Clause' queries is anti pattern in Cassandra since you are trying to access multiple partition in same query. This may cause in timeout in some cases.
2. It solves the purpose without complexity.